# How to sending a toast notification from the desktop without creating shortcut

Tags: windows, message, toast

I got a requirement to show a toast notification from a desktop application, i follow the instruction from the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

According to this instruction, i must create a shortcut to my app, with a System.AppUserModel.ID,but the problem is, the shortcut will display under "all apps" screen in win8, but i dont want the shortcut shown there, so is there anyway to avoid creating the shortcut, or hide the shortcut. Thansk!

OS: Win8

Comment: "A shortcut to your app, with a System.AppUserModel.ID, must be installed to the Start screen" is quite clear that the shortcut is a requirement.

Comment: Yes,i know that, i just wonder whether there is a workaround to hide the shrotuct from all apps

Comment: If such a workaround existed, it would be considered a bug, and any program that relied on it would be at risk of breaking in a future service pack. Make sure your customers understand this.